# Modem connects but no internet connection Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, server, internet, usb-modem

I have **modem** with which I connect to the internet, and it works fine on-till when I installed [Best resume ever](https://github.com/salomonelli/best-resume-ever) a node.js package on github and later when I  try connecting to internet using  the modem, modem connects fine but when I try opening any page on a browser I get ***server not found error*** or when I ping i get the error ***Name or service not known***

Using the same modem on other machine works no problem. I am guessing the package I installed edited some of my system setting( proxy settings ).

I browser fine when I connect to a wifi.

I appreciate any help on how to fix this.

**update:**

After total re-installation of Ubuntu( 17.04 ), everything worked fine for a while, unfortunately the-same issues came up again.

Comment: you said 'when you ping you get the error Name or service not known'... did you mean **ping google.com** or **ping 8.8.8.8** ? if you can ping 8.8.8.8 but you can't ping google.com, the problem is in your DNS in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @Deki Akbar Your right. i could **ping 8.8.8.8.8** but not google.com. what is the /etc/resolve.conf  to contain

Answer (score 2):

just add the google DNS address to your resolv.conf, open your terminal and then tipe this :

> sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf

it will add dns server to your ubuntu , the **/etc/resolv.conf** is an config file to setup DNS on your machine,,, AFAIK this method work for me, so I hope this work for you to, if your problem solved please mark as solved this question, Hope this help you

Comment: Works. The file( link ) is auto generated at startup. this just override the contents which is then overwriting again. how can one make it permanent?

Comment: to make it as permanent , type this **sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base** , after that type in terminal **resolvconf -u** , tell me if it works , if there is something , please reply this comment, thanks :)

Comment: nop didn't work

Comment: its did not work?? have you try to restart the system?? is there an error message ??

Answer (score 1):

The problem definitely seems to be with DNS. To resolve it, you must first find what is the proper DNS for your network (you can user google's one 8.8.8.8 but this is not the most elegant solution).

If you are using Network Manager, open the settings off your modem connection, switch to IPv4 tab, and type your DNS address in the "DNS servers" field: be it either your provider's DNS, Google's or both separated with comma (the last option is recommended).